# mac osx gatekeeper is allowing unsigned packages to get installed

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store, package, osx-gatekeeper

I have created some packages using pkgbuild and productbuild (without signing). At first time of the installation mac gatekeeper prevented it from installing

My Gatekeeper settings at the time was - Allow apps downloaded from : Mac App store and Identified developers

For the sake of testing I changed the setting to - Allow apps downloaded from : Anywhere

Then the installation is allowed without any problem, but after that changing the gatekeeper to previous setting is of no use and it still allows the old package to get installed. Why is this happening and how should I prevent this from not happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GateKeeper maintains a list of previously approved applications. If you want to remove an application from that list you can use the OSX utility `spctl`.
It has been clearly explained in this [post](http://www.theinstructional.com/guides/gatekeeper-fundamentals-part-2).